# Render the select form items dynamically as per the user select the dropdown value in REACT?

Tags: reactjs

Hello there so today I have this confusion on how to dynamically render more select dropdown options.
The scene is during a form submittion user has to select a category and if he select a category having sub category I have to render the next select dropdown. The data I get from api looks like this.

```
{
  "id": "f35dc7d2-755e-4531-981b-6862bbb97512",
  "name": "Mobile & Accesories",
  "image": null,
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "d038c127-d3f8-47f6-a47b-0f4b625e8caf",
      "name": "Handsets",
      "image": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "ab46c001-7d8e-4784-99de-eb26f67dc4e2",
          "name": "Smartphone",
          "image": "",
          "categories": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So at last, if there are no inner categories the final one's id should be used to send to the api.
I know working with react hooks so it would be helpful if I can get some help or the logics to accomplish this task.

Comment: The dependent dropdown can be used here.
On basic to First dropdown content in next dropdown will occur.

Comment: @ShahVipul yes i could have used dependent dropdown but there is not certainity on how deep the nesting can go

Comment: use a loop and at the time of render is will automatically create a new dropdown.
Also, use the ternary operator to check where the next steps contain  nesting element or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create those Dynamic Dropdowns using Recursion for the Same Component.

Here is the Code Sandbox demo from the API Data you have given:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-paper-4cu6l?file=/src/SimpleSelect.js

Comment: The recursion way helped me to acheive this task. Thank you for the guidance